# Why is my gl.generateMipmap returning GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Tags: webgl2

I'm trying to create mipmaps for a texture initialized with `gl.texStorage2d()`, but I'm getting `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when calling `gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D )`. My test texture is 128x128 and displays fine without mipmaps.

I can create mipmaps without using texStorage, but I read somewhere that it allows the driver to perform more efficiently. I'm using Chrome  57.0.2987.133 on macOS Sierra with NVIDIA GT 750M.

How can I fix the error while still using texStorage?

I also noticed that my code works without errors if I replace `gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8` with `gl.RGBA8`, but I want to use the former.

```
function handleLoadedTexture( image )
{
    let textTexture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, textTexture );
    gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0 );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, Math.log2( image.width ) );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    gl.texStorage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, Math.log2( image.width ), gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8, image.width, image.height );
    gl.texSubImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image );

    gl.generateMipmap( gl.TEXTURE_2D );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in either Chrome or the WebGL2 spec.

Chrome generates an WebGL error.

```
[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-0x7fee3e069600]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap:
```

Firefox prints an error in the Web Console but does not generate a WebGL error

```
Error: WebGL: texSubImage2D: Conversion requires pixel reformatting.
```

Firefox's error might just actually be a speed warning but it's not clear.

Even trying without `gl.texStorage2D` the same thing happens.

```js
const gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl2");
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

const tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texStorage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, Math.log2( canvas.width ), gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8, canvas.width, canvas.height );
gl.texSubImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
log("should be no error was:", getGLErrorString(gl.getError()));

const tex2 = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas );
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
log("should be no error was:", getGLErrorString(gl.getError()));

function getGLErrorString(v) {
  if (v === 0) {
    return "NO_ERROR";
  }
  for (key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === v) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return "0x" + key.toString(16);
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

[Filed a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=712096)

Comment: That Firefox error made me try `gl.RGBA8` instead of `gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8` and it works. Let's hope they fix the bug, and thanks for writing WebGL2 Fundamentals by the way!

Comment: The error/warning in Firefox is gone in Firefox Nightly 55.0a1 (2017-04-16) (64-bit)